# Sorting an array based on alphabets?

Tags: javascript

I need to sort an array based on Alphabets. I have tried sort() method of javascript, but it doesn't work since my array consists of numbers, lowercase letters and uppercase letters. Can anybody please help me out with this? Thanks

For e.g my array is:

```
[
    "@Basil",
    "@SuperAdmin",
    "@Supreme",
    "@Test10",
    "@Test3",
    "@Test4",
    "@Test5",
    "@Test6",
    "@Test7",
    "@Test8",
    "@Test9",
    "@a",
    "@aadfg",
    "@abc",
    "@abc1",
    "@abc2",
    "@abc5",
    "@abcd",
    "@abin",
    "@akrant",
    "@ankur",
    "@arsdarsd",
    "@asdd",
    "@ashaa",
    "@aviral",
    "@ayush.kansal",
    "@chris",
    "@dgji",
    "@dheeraj",
    "@dsfdsf",
    "@dualworld",
    "@errry",
    "@george",
    "@ggh",
    "@gjhggjghj"
]
```

Comment: What "Alphabets" would you like it to be sorted after if that doesn't contain letters and numbers? *What* is wrong with the default Alphabet, what result do you expect?

Comment: Array seems sorted to me...

Comment: What exactly is your desired output?

Comment: @Christoph case insensitive I would imagine

Comment: @Bergi:  "@" is consistent in the array that I get from the backend,the next letter to it must start with an 'a' or'A'. Say in my example,the first result should be any instances of '@a' then '@aadc' '@abc1' '@abc2' '@chris'  and so on

Comment: @NimChimpsky while this sounds logical, as long as the OP does not explicitly confirm that, it still is only a guess...

Comment: @Christoph: if the letter starts with an 'A' or 'a' ,then it should be listed first,In my case the priority is set based on lowercase and uppercase. like this way: - '@ABC','acd','aed', '@Bc' ,'@bella' etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a.sort(function(a, b) {
    var textA = a.toUpperCase();
    var textB = b.toUpperCase();
    return (textA < textB) ? -1 : (textA > textB) ? 1 : 0;
});
```

[This](http://jsfiddle.net/riri78/8hP9v/) should work (jsFiddle)

Answer (score 4):

```
function alphabetical(a, b){
     var c = a.toLowerCase();
     var d = b.toLowerCase();
     if (c < d){
        return -1;
     }else if (c > d){
       return  1;
     }else{
       return 0;
     }
}


yourArray.sort(alphabetical);
```

Answer (score 1):

To sort an array by a key function applied to an element (`toUpperCase` here), [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), aka "decorate-sort-undecorate" is your technique of choice:

```
cmp = function(x, y) { return x > y ? 1 : x < y ? -1 : 0 }

sorted = array.map(function(x) {
    return [x.toUpperCase(), x]
}).sort(function(x, y) {
    return cmp(x[0], y[0])
}).map(function(x) {
    return x[1]
})
```

The major advantage of this approach is that the key function is called exactly once for each element, which can matter when the key is heavy or has side effects.

I realize that you're looking for a simple answer right now, but this might be something for you to consider learning in the future.

Comment: No, it yields `["a!", "a"]` while it should be `["a", "a!"]`. You will need to sort by the decorated part of the array only.

Comment: @Bergi: I don't see any `["a!", "a"]` in the question.

Comment: Of course it's not in the question, OP only posted an *example* array. How can you be sure that his actual data will contain none of `!"#$%&'()*+`?

Comment: @thg435 well, the argument "It works on the 3 example values" is not much of a valid standpoint for arguing. Although I like the general approach of using a ST, therefore +1 for the general concept.